# DOMNodeInserted/Removed event polyfills (or similar events)

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mutation-observers, dom3

I need a way to listen for changes for when a node's children are removed or added. I made an autoscrolling plugin that keeps an element scrolled to the bottom as new items are added. The event I'm listening to is `DOMNodeInserted` and `DOMNodeRemoved`.

I was looking for polyfills for [`DOMNodeInserted` and `DOMNodeRemoved`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmcxjla.php). Looking around I wasn't able to find any that already existed. The event is not supported in all browsers and is [currently deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted).I have a simple (likely naive) polyfill I wrote quickly but I doubt it works (well).

I know these [events are deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted), but is there a better way to listen for element children changes?

```
(function() {
    var works = false;
    var $test = document.createElement("div");
    var $testchild = document.createElement("a");

    $test.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function() {
        works = true;
    }, false);

    $test.appendChild($testchild);

    if(!works) {
        var nodeproto = Node.prototype;
        var nativeAppend = nodeproto.appendChild;
        var nativeRemove = nodeproto.removeChild;

        nodeproto.appendChild = function() {
            nativeAppend.apply(this, arguments);
            this.fireEvent("DOMNodeInserted");
        };

        nodeproto.removeChild = function() {
            nativeRemove.apply(this, arguments);
            this.fireEvent("DOMNodeRemoved");
        };
    }
})();
```

Comment: There's always the [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) object for **modern browsers**. For old browsers you have no other choice than using an override approach, however like you said it might be hard to implement something that will work cross-browser because not all browsers will expose the DOM objects such as `Element`.

Comment: That's true - probably be better to polyfill the mutationobserver as it will not apply to node's we're not watching. I also saw some keyframe animation hack methods but I don't think I could get them working for ie>7

Comment: It will be even harder to polyfill the `MutationObserver`. At a small scale you could always use `observedEl.cloneNode()` to take a snapshot of the node at specific intervals and recursively compare the `childNodes` with the live element. If you know which targets might be observed, you can then do something like `startObserving(node)` which would fire `DOMNodeInserted`/`DOMNOdeRemoved` events on these nodes when a change is detected.

Comment: I found a few mutationobserver polyfills which already exist and fall back on the inserted/remove event http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18269/simple-dom-mutation-abstraction https://github.com/Polymer/MutationObservers. Guess I'll look into these, thanks @plalx

Comment: Unfortunately I believe these are built upon other features that aren't supported by old browsers either, but give it a try.

Comment: https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element/blob/master/src/dre-ie8-upfront-fix.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing [a reasonably compliant polyfill](https://github.com/megawac/MutationObserver.js) for `MutationObserver` using interval checks of a cloned `childList` (similar to what @plalx mentioned in his comments) instead of falling back on the `MutationEvent`s. `MutationEvent`s will be more performant for most scenarios as any poll vs interrupt implementations but compatibility sucks

[Simple auto scrolling example using my shim](http://jsbin.com/uxAQEWuL/10)